# what is the task of a display server protocol?

Tags: shell, user-interface, server, display

I am doing a presentation about GUIs and I could not find out, what a display server protocol does exactly.
Could you answer my "simple" question?

To be more precise, an explanation of this diagram would be helpful[image]